# str and ldr instruction does not use same address

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, mmu

I have this strange problem where the MMU translate memory for str but not for ldr instruction. I'm compiling using gcc (no optimization) for an arm7TDMI.

The program enter a function and store 4 parameters in the stack(r0 to r3)
I have theses registers :

```
r0 = 0x1e10c8
r1 = 0x12adf0
r2 = 0x0
r3 = 0x2
r11 = 0x12ade4
```

The MMU is active and everything between 0x0 and 0x00FFFFFF is located physically between  0xC0000000 and 0xC0FFFFFF

The pc execute this 4 lines of assembly :

```
str r0, [r11, #-24]
str r1, [r11, #-28]
str r2, [r11, #-32]
strb r3, [r11, #-33]
```

This is the range of memory , where the data is stored after execution :

```
0xC012ADC0  02000000  ....
0xC012ADC4  00000000  ....
0xC012ADC8  0012ADF0  ð­..
0xC012ADCC  001E10C8  È...
```

And this range of memory is at FF

```
0x0012ADC0  FFFFFFFF  ÿÿÿÿ
0x0012ADC4  FFFFFFFF  ÿÿÿÿ
0x0012ADC8  FFFFFFFF  ÿÿÿÿ
0x0012ADCC  FFFFFFFF  ÿÿÿÿ
```

We see that the data was physically stored in the 0xC0000000 region because of the MMU.

Because I'm in debug mode, I can change manually this area with the following value:

```
0x0012ADC0  F4F4F4F4  ôôôô
0x0012ADC4  3F3F3F3F  ????
0x0012ADC8  F2F2F2F2  òòòò
0x0012ADCC  1F1F1F1F  ....
```

Now 2-3 assembly execution later, I have this assembly line :

```
ldr r3, [r11, #-24]
```

I execute this line and I have this value in r3:

```
r3=0x1f1f1f1f
```

(if I don't change the memory between 0x0012ADC0 and 0x0012ADCC I normally get 0xFFFFFFFF...)

I really do not understand why r3 is not equal to 0x1E10C8. It's like the MMU does its job when the str command is executed, but when ldr is executed, the MMU is not translating the address(0x0012ADCC instead of 0xC012ADCC). There is something I cannot understand here.

Just in case, here is a snap of the assembly instruction involved :

```
      kapiReceiveQueue:
000195fc:   push {r11, lr}
00019600:   add r11, sp, #4
00019604:   sub sp, sp, #32
00019608:   str r0, [r11, #-24]         <----- r0 stored physically at C012ADCC
0001960c:   str r1, [r11, #-28]
00019610:   str r2, [r11, #-32]
00019614:   strb r3, [r11, #-33]    ; 0x21
 693          switch (Option)
00019618:   ldrb r3, [r11, #-33]    ; 0x21
0001961c:   cmp r3, #2
00019620:   beq 0x1974c <kapiReceiveQueue+336>
...
0001974c:   ldr r3, [r11, #-24]         <------ r3 get the value of physical address 0x12ADCC
00019750:   ldr r2, [r3]
00019754:   sub r3, r11, #17
00019758:   mov r0, r2
```

If this has any relation with my compilations flags, here they are :

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -march=armv4t -mcpu=arm7tdmi -dp  -DNG_COMP_GCC -c
-Wa,-adhlns="../../Base/Lib/Pa/Kapi.o.lst" -fmessage-length=0 -fno-zero-initialized-
in-bss -MMD -MP -MF"../../Base/Lib/Pa/Kapi.d" -MT"../../Base/Lib/Pa/Kapi.d" -fpic
-mlittle-endian -Wall -DNGHW_TOPMEM_ADDR=0x00800000 -DNG_CPU_ARM -DNG_CPU_ARMv4T 
-DNG_CODE_ARM -DNG_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DNG_DEBUG -DNG_RTOS -DNG_COMP_GCC -DNG_RTOS_UCOSII 
-DDHCP_CLIENT -g3 -gdwarf-2  ../../Base/Kernel/Alos/Ucos-II/Kapi.c -o"../../Base/Lib/Pa/Kapi.o"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: How are you inspecting and changing memory in "debug mode"? If this is an ARM7TDMI, then there's no memory coherency between physical and virtual, or even two virtual mappings, and if you're looking at or changing the raw physical contents, it won't be reflected in the cache. That will result in weird MMU behavior (although it's not really the MMU at fault - it's a caching issue).

Comment: How is the hardware physically mapped?  Are addresses fully decoded or are they aliased?  Is your hardware well tested?